# Open and repair multiple Excel files using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Google Sheets and making reports in Microsoft Excel. I am working on almost 50+ sheets. Each week I copy and paste data into Excel one by one to keep the cell formatting.

I tried to download the entire folder which contains Google Sheets then open it in Microsoft Excel. This gave me an error while opening each:
[image]

Once I click OK it populates one more error:
[[image]

How can I fix this error instead of opening each file separately then saving it to make it repairable (so the error could not appear again).

I tried with below code. I need to apply this method on the entire folder to repair all Excel files and save them.

```vb
Sub Folder()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim I As Long

With Application.FileDialog(4)
    If .Show Then
        strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "You haven't selected a folder!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
    strFolder = strFolder & "\"
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx*")
Do While strFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile, CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)
    For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
    Next wsh
    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
    strFile = Dir

    Exit Sub
Err_Open:
    Err.Clear
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly does it "not work"? In your while loop, there's an `Exit Sub` and you also loop through the sheets without doing anything there?

Comment: Please, use `CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile` instead of `CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile` and comment the next code lines: `Exit Sub`, `Err_Open:`, `Err.Clear`. These three lines make sense only to avoid errors which may appear, but to use them, you must have `On Error Goto Err_Open` before the respective loop and **the respective code lines to be moved outside the loop**. Iterating between sheets doing nothing looks useless, but this will not bother the code working logic...

Comment: Sorry for being late. The issue issue when i run the code it opens the first file from the selected folder and then above 2nd error is popuped with the window to save the workbook manually.  
@Notus_Panda

Comment: Sorry for being late. Thank you very much @FaneDuru i tried and its working but there is single issue that the above code should automatically save the workbooks rather than when run the code and save the  workbook manually one by one.

Comment: Then, try placing the saving code  line (`wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True`) between the next two code lines: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, respectively `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`... If it does not work (probably, being a recovered one, Excel wants to save it in a different place), you should use something like:  `wbk.SaveCopyAs FilePath & "\" & FileName`. Where `FilePath`  shold be defined as a different folder and `FileName` should be extracted from the existing one.  Followed by `wbk.Close False`... When using `SaveCopyAs`, this does  not change `wbk` in memory.

Comment: If it does not bother you. Can you please post an answer. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @HSHO OK, I will place an answer, but not right now...

Comment: I will really appreciate your help @FaneDuru

Comment: Ups... I was very busy yesterday and after a while I forgot about it... I will do it know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will create a subfolder "RecoveredWB" in the selected folder to be processed and all processed files will be saved in this one:

```
Sub Folder()
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    With Application.FileDialog(4)
        If .Show Then
          strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
          MsgBox "You haven't selected a folder!", vbExclamation
          Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
      strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If
    
    Dim wbName As String, arrWb, subFoldNew As String
    subFoldNew = strFolder & "RecoveredWB"
     'create RecoveredWB folder if not existing:
      If Dir(subFoldNew, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir subFoldNew
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")
    Do While strFile <> ""
      Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
      For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
      Next wsh
      
      arrWb = Split(wbk.fullname, "\") 'place the full name in an array split by "\"
      wbName = arrWb(UBound(arrWb)) 'the workbook name (without path)
      
      wbk.SaveCopyAs subFoldNew & "\" & wbName
      
      wbk.Close False
      
      strFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code is  not tested, I cannot reproduce the situation, not having corrupted workbooks...

If something goes wrong, please explain which error on which code line, or what it does not against what it should.

Comment: thank you that you spare some time here is the error https://ibb.co/5jQTwgW on the line `strFile = Dir`

Comment: Hi if you want i can share that workbooks @FaneDuru

Comment: @HSHO OK, please share two such workbooks.

Comment: @HSHO OK, I will download them now...

Comment: @HSHO Downloaded. I will start testing... You my delete the comment.

Comment: @HSHO Please, try the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much @FaneDuru for this favor. It is working very fine

Comment: Sorry to bother you is is possible to apply this code on multiple folder @Faneduru

Comment: @HSHO Probably, yes... But you must clearly explain what you understand by "multiple folder". Where from to be taken  a list of the folders to be processed? Are they subfolders of a specific folder root? Do you have a list of such folders somewhere in your file, array etc.?

Comment: Let me explain it better. I have 1 folder which contains 10+ subfolders and these subfolders have Excel Files. No more subfolders

Comment: @HSHO Theoretically, the above code can be used as a main part of the code, but iteration between subfolders must be done differently. If you mix `Dir` to extract files with `Dir` to check a specific folder existence, the first `Dir` is lost... So was happened in the previous code version, for only a folder. Please, use the code you have now (the above one) and place a new question, clearly explain of what you want accomplishing. The number of subfolders is not relevant. If you tag me here and I will be available, I will try helping. If not, somebody else will answer it...

Comment: I have posted a new question [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74689606/loop-through-folder-and-then-subdfolders-vba) here @FaneDuru

Comment: @HSHO I am afraid, you did not structure your question as it should and it has already be deleted... I would suggest you to wait some time, to start your question with the existing code and then ask the question. Not mention about subfolders... It will make people reading to think (preponderantly) about iterating between subfolders... Now i am leaving my office...

Comment: Alright i will upload a question later with some understanding of it