# VBA Excel - repairing multiple files doesn't work from the sharepoint desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to bulk repair my corrupted Excel filed by the VBA code, like shown here:

[Open and Repair Multiple excel Files using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74627944/open-and-repair-multiple-excel-files-using-vba)

It works well in any directory, except of the situation, when I place my folder on the desktop. Because my desktop is linked to the SharePoint I am unable to make the process, as I keep getting  the 1004 error:
[image]
[image]

```
 My piece of code looks like this:
  If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
   strFolder = strFolder & "\"
  End If

 Dim wbName As String, arrWb, subFoldNew As String
 subFoldNew = strFolder & "Recovered"
 'create RecoveredWB folder if not existing:
  If Dir(subFoldNew, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir subFoldNew
  
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsm")    
 Do While strFile <> ""
  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
  For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
  Next wsh
  
  arrWb = Split(wbk.FullName, "\") 'place the full name in an array split by "\"
  wbName = arrWb(UBound(arrWb)) 'the workbook name (without path)
  'On Error Resume Next
  wbk.SaveCopyAs subFoldNew & "\" & wbName
  
  'wbk.Save
  
  wbk.Close False
  
  strFile = Dir
  Loop
```

The error appears exactly at this line:

```
  wbk.SaveCopyAs subFoldNew & "\" & wbName
```

when I use the On Error Resume Next - then my "Recovered" folder is empty

I found some solution here:
[Open an Excel file from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site)
but didn't work for me.

How could I manage with this problem?

Comment: `arrWb = Split(wbk.FullName, "\")` URL's are delimited by / not by \    You haven't shown us where you get `strFolder`, which is kind of a key part of your code...

Comment: Ok I've added this bit of code. Will it  be enough for you?

Comment: Please show the *complete* code you're trying to use.